# Asus Eee PC taking too long during system repair.

Tags: windows-7, system-restore, asus-laptop, eee-pc

my Asus Eee PC was dropped on the cement floor and completely stopped responding. Tried reseated the battery and the last few days when it starts Windows 7 goes into a startup repair where it is "checking your system for problems" and then stays checking for as long as I leave it checking. I have left it for 9,and 18 hours. It never stops checking. The hard drive sounds funny now.

Comment: Time to get a new timex!